# react bootstrap modal - how do I get it to show?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a component in which I am importing reactBootstrap:

```
import ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Then I have a function in my component that's triggered when the user clicks a button:

```
onClickBtn : function() {
  var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
  return (
    <Modal>
      ... 
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

However, I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'Modal' of undefined.

I am having trouble following the guide on react-bootstrap and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to easily import modal.  Thanks

Comment: what happens if you use import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

Comment: hi @bmartin I tried that and now it says "ReactBootstrap is not defined"  EDIT:  sorry i'm an idiot.  However, how should the var Modal = part be changed?

Comment: OK nvm so I don't need the var Modal part.

Comment: However, now nothing happens.  No errors, but nothing happens :(

Comment: I think that you now have the Modal component loaded.  Beyond that, I think that any other issues would require another question to be asked.  However, I would take a look at https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html and the modal basic example for some guidance on why nothing may be happening (maybe something like set the show property to true for the Modal component?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can import any component directly from 'react-bootstrap' using the following es6 syntax:

```
import { Component } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

In this particular case, you can use:

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

You can also import multiple components at once, such as:

```
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

The need for { } is because these are not default exports, they are named exports that can be referred to by name.

Comment: thanks.  now trying to figure out why nothing comes up even after messing with the show modal in state: (*

Comment: After trying to solve the issue for a while, you can post another question that is centered around that issue. :)